# Show that $z^n+nz-1$ has $n$ zeros in $D(0,R)$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Let $n\geq 3$.  Show that the polynomial $z^n+nz-1$ has $n$ zeros in $D(0,R)$, where
$$R=1+\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^{1/2}.$$

I was hoping to use Induction and Rouche's Theorem.  For the base case (n=3) I was easily able to show that the polynomial has $3$ zeros inside $|z|=R$.  It's the base case that's giving me trouble.  I assume that, for $k\geq 3$, the polynomial has exactly $k$ zeros inside $|z|=1+\left(\frac{2}{k-1}\right)^{1/2}$.  Then I want to look at what happens with the polynomial $z^{k+1}+(k+1)z-1$.  Letting $f(z)=z^{k+1}$, $g(z)=(k+1)z-1$, and considering $R=1+\left(\frac{2}{k}\right)^{1/2}$, I can't figure out the moduli of $f$ and $g$ and compare them to verify that I can use Rouche's Theorem.

Is induction the wrong way to go here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On $|z|=R$ we have that $|z^n|=R^n$ and

$$|nz-1|\leq nR+1=n+n\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^{1/2}+1$$

If we prove that

> $$n+n\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^{1/2}+1<\left(1+\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^{1/2}\right)^n$$

then $$|nz-1|<|z^n|$$ on $|z|=R$ and by Rouche $z^n+nz-1$ and $z^n$ have the same number of zeros in the interior of $|z|=R$.

It is the inequality above the one you would like to prove for $n\geq3$.

We can expand using the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) $$\begin{align}\left(1+\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^{1/2}\right)^n&=1+n\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^{1/2}+\underbrace{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)}\limits_{n}+\text{ other positive terms}\\&>1+n\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^{1/2}+n\end{align}$$

Therefore the inequality is satisfied.